# Angular handling observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

I have an angular component that merges a number of lists.  All that works fine but when I want to clean up the arrays which contain the selected Items I get into problems with Angular's change detection.

the code in the component looks like

```
  this.listsService.merge(result.name, mergedListsIds)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.newlyAddedId = resp[0];
        this.snackBar.open(`Successfully Merged '${mergedLists.length}' lists into '${result.name}'`, 'OK', {
          duration: 3000
        });
        this.populateListsData();
        this.selectedLists = [];
        this.selectedListsIds = [];
        this.selectedPromotedLists = [];
        this.selectedPromotedListsIds = [];
      });
```

Everything works fine apart from the resetting of the arrays in paticulart the selectedLists and selectedPromotedLists array.

I get the following error.

```
An Error Occurred Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

If I comment out the array reset everything works fine.  I have moved them outside the subscribe but if I try that and the merge fails the user looses all the lists that were selected.

Is there a way to add these into the subscribe so they are only reset on a successful call to the merge service?  I've been reading up on changedetection but a lot of it seems overkill for such a simple task.  I also don't want to wrap things in setTimeout as that feels hacky

Comment: See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005

Comment: is any of these lists are inputs or outputs of component or do you share data between different instance of components?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova No They are simply Javascrip array's.  When a user selects a checkbox, a list is added to the appropriate array.